# Why is the MongoCursor not returning all results from a MongoCollection?

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I'm using the 10gen c# MongoDB driver from mongodb.org and I'm attempting to get all the rows from a collection that has 2 Million+ rows.  Here is the code:

```
var mongoServer = dataHelper.GetMongoServer();
var mongoDatabase = mongoServer.GetDatabase("MyDB");
var mongoCollection = mongoDatabase.GetCollection<MyClass>("MyClass");
var mongoCount = mongoCollection.Count();
var mongoCursor = mongoCollection.FindAll();
mongoCursor.SetBatchSize(1000);
var totalCount = 0;

foreach(var myClass in mongoCursor)
{
    ++totalCount;
    //process record
}
```

When the foreach statement is complete totalCount is only about 91% of the mongoCount the collection has in it.  Is there something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

1 Mb yous issue because of you changed Batch Size?  Because the default batch size is actually 4mb. Try without set batch size.

2 Did you tried to set limit directly for example to 3 millions?

3 Also did you tried to get data in parts, for example by half of million, because mb some timeout at mongodb or at the driver?

4 About [cuncurrency](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/How+does+concurrency+work) at mongo db.

Hope this help.

Comment: I believe count in this case is not actually a Linq method because the count is instantaneous.  If it was actually deserializing all the records it would take much longer.  The result I get from mongoCollection.Count() is the same as when I do a count query from the mongo shell.  I've also tried it with out setting the batch size and I got the same result.

Comment: Yes about count you was right, i just not accuratly read you code.

Comment: Do you know if mongo locks records for writes prevent the cursor from retrieving them?